# PHP select array elements

Tags: php, arrays, function, dynamic, preg-match

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

$pid = '129';

$families = array
(
      "Griffin"=>array
                      (
                      "PTY"=>"Peter",
                      "STY"=>"Z",
                      "QTY"=>"A|F"
                      ),
      "Quagmire"=>array
                      (
                      "NTY"=>"Glenn"
                      ),
      "Brown"=>array
                  (
                  "FTY"=>"Cleveland",
                  "OTY"=>"Q|G|T|Y",
                  "PTY"=>"Junior"
                  )
);


function buildid($pid,$key,$val){
    $id = $pid.'-'.$key.'-'.$val;
    // echo '<br>';

    if (preg_match("/\|/",$id)){
        $id = explode("|",$id);
        print_r($id);
    }
    return;
}

  foreach($families as $familieskey=>$familiesvalue){
    foreach($familiesvalue as $skey=>$sval){
        buildid("$pid","$skey","$sval");
    }
  }

echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Execute the above code and you ll get all the data processed with an `$id` but my requirement is, once if I find `$id` with `|` I want like below,

Case2: I also want keys and values like `"STY"=>"Z",` in this there are no `|` but I want the value. **So is there any way I can select keys such as `STY`, `QTY` and `OTY` only and process them?**

**Present output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 129-QTY-A
    [1] => F
)
Array
(
    [0] => 129-OTY-Q
    [1] => G
    [2] => T
    [3] => Y
)
```

**Expected output:**

```
129-QTY-A
129-QTY-F
129-OTY-Q
129-OTY-G
129-OTY-T
129-OTY-Y
```

Comment: you can use an foreach on the explode and concat the existing text

Comment: Why you are passing the variables to `buildid` like this? `buildid("$pid","$skey","$sval");`. You should do it like `buildid($pid,$skey,$sval);`

Comment: Is there any much difference Tomas? - demonofnight - say it with a code

Comment: Absolutely nothing. But take in account that you are forcing the PHP compiler to do first an extension of the values of those variables and cast them to a string. Without the quotes you are simple passing the variables to the function. Though there is no noticeable performance gain if you change it, you should do it to improve clarity ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating $id after exploding the $val will solve this issue.

```
function buildid($pid,$key,$val){
        if (preg_match("/\|/",$val)){
            $val = explode("|",$val);
            foreach($val as $val1)
            {
                 $id = $pid.'-'.$key.'-'.$val1;
                 echo "<br>";       
                 print_r($id);
            }    
       }
  }
```

Comment: Why `return` not needed?

Comment: Because, You are not passing the variable outside the function. You have printed the variable inside the function itself.

Comment: The fact is will have to use it outside since only the part that I had doubt is being posted here...return to you later. Thank you for help!

Comment: I am getting this error after a certain number of `echo` happened `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare buildid() (previously declared in` any idea How do avoid this?

Comment: I think, function declaration is executing another time. Try to keep the function declaration outside every loop. This could solve your problem.

Comment: I want this function call `buildid("$pid","$skey","$sval");` only inside the loop also please check the `case2:` mentioned in the question.

Comment: For case2: as below:

`function buildidsingle($pid,$key,$val){
 echo $id = $pid.'-'.$key.'-'.$val;
 echo '<br>';
}
  
  foreach($families as $familieskey=>$familiesvalue){
 foreach($familiesvalue as $skey=>$sval){

  $adleng = strlen($sval);
  if($adleng == 1){
   buildidsingle("$pid","$skey","$sval");
  }
  
  buildid("$pid","$skey","$sval");
 }
  }`

Comment: **I want to print it outside the function, How to do that?** I tried some methods and it doesn't works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43101/discussion-between-banned-from-so-and-sriraman)

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildid($pid,$key,$val){

    if (preg_match("/\|/",$val)){
        $id = explode("|",$val);
        $data = array();
        foreach($id as $entity){
          $data[] = $pid.'-'.$key.'-'.$entity;
        }
        print_r($data);
    }
    return;
}
```